# I would like to create a function that reads each line of the input and produces its sum and save that as sum.txt using C++

Tags: c++, iostream

Let's assume that I have the following input:

```
1 2 3 
5 6
10 11
13
```

stored in `wow.txt`.

I would like to create a function that reads each line of the input and 
produces its sum and save that as `sum.txt` using C++.

In the input file, we have the following:

1) we don't know the length of each line, but it has at most 10 integers.
2) each integer is separated by a space.

So I started with

```
ifstream inFile;
inFile.open("wow.txt");
ofstream outFile;
outFile.open("sum.txt");
```

and wasn't sure what to do next.

Some of my friends recommended me using getline, tokenize each line, and then 
convert string to integer, but I was wondering if there are easier ways of doing it
without having to change the type (int to string, string to int) back and forth.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `easier ways of reading the input line by line` the function's called `getline`, how much easier were you hoping this to be? Just try something and if you get stuck come back.

Comment: Do you want the sum of all the numbers or just the ones for each line?

Comment: 0x499602D2  just one for each line.

Comment: "some of my friends recommended me using `getline`, tokenize each line, and then convert string to integer" - get some new friends.  You should use `getline`, then create an `istringstream` from the line you've read, then have a `while` loop reading numbers from the `istringstream` - far simpler than explicitly "tokenize"-ing the lines or manually doing `string`->`int` conversions.  I could write it but then you'd learn nothing.

Comment: Yang Unfortunately, I don't have enough reputation to upvote answers... (you need at least 15 reputation to upvote, but I have 14).

Comment: Yang i have 19 now. I accepted and upvoted yours.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using [`getline`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/) and [`istringstream`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/istringstream/):

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  ifstream inFile("wow.txt");
  if (!inFile) {
    cerr << "File wow.txt not found." << endl;
    return -1;
  }
  ofstream outFile("sum.txt");

  // Using getline() to read one line at a time.
  string line;
  while (getline(inFile, line)) {
    if (line.empty()) continue;

    // Using istringstream to read the line into integers.
    istringstream iss(line);
    int sum = 0, next = 0;
    while (iss >> next) sum += next;
    outFile << sum << endl;
  }

  inFile.close();
  outFile.close();
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
6
11
21
13
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a big fan of the `std::getline()` and then use `std::istringstream` approach: streams aren't free to create. At the very least, the inner `std::istringstream should be constructed once and then be reset, even though this requires to clear the flags:

```
std::istringstream iss;
for (std::string line; std::getline(std::cin, line); ) {
    iss.clear();
    iss.str(line);
    // ...
}
```

The call to `iss.clear()` resets the stream's error flags which get set to eventually indicate that there is no more data. With `iss.str(line)` the string stream's internal data is set.

Instead of creating or setting an `std::istringstream` I would arrange for the newline to set the input stream to be false, i.e., to have `std::ios_base::failbit` set. For the advanced approach to do so, I'd change the definition of whitespace for the `std:ctype<char>` facet in the `std::locale` used by the stream. However, that's shooting the big guns! For the task at hand, a simple manipulator used before each input can be used to a similar effect:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cctype>

using namespace std;

std::istream& skipspace(std::istream& in) {
    while (std::isspace(in.peek())) {
        int c(in.peek());
        in.ignore();
        if (c == '\n') {
            in.setstate(std::ios_base::failbit);
            break;
        }
    }
    return in;
}

int main() {
    int sum(0);
    while (std::cin >> sum) {
        for (int value; std::cin >> skipspace >> value; ) {
            sum += value;
        }
        std::cout << "sum: " << sum << "\n";
        std::cin.clear();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Most of the magic is in the *manipulator* `skipspace()`: it skips whitespace until either the end of the stream is reached or a newline is consumed. If a newline is consumed, it puts the stream into failure state by setting the flag `std::ios_base::failbit`.

The loop computing the sum simply reads the first value. If this fails, e.g., because a non-integer is found, the input fails and no further output is generated. Otherwise whitespace is skipped using the `skipspace()` followed by reading the next value. If either of these fails, the current `sum` is printed and the stream is cleared for the next sum to be read.